# Google Sheets installable trigger: entire function is within try-catch, but errors still occur

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling, try-catch

I have an entire function wrapped within a try-catch but still get error notifications.

The catch is supposed to ignore this error because it is benign; i.e. I do not re-throw the error after catching it.

```
function myOnEdit(event){
  try{
    //stuff
  }catch(e){
    if((e.message).indexOf("Must be") != -1){
      return;
    }else{
      //e-mail me the error and display a user-friendly dialogue to the end user
    }
  }
}
```

I expect not to be notified of any errors containing the words "Must be." This code is tied to a spreadsheet with data validation, and all the data validation errors are custom set to an error message of "Must be" followed by the required format. For instance, one column lists phone numbers, so the data validation error is, "Must be ###-###-####."

Instead, I receive the automated Google e-mail "Summary of failures" listing errors for these data validations:

> Your script, SED Code - PRD, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below. To configure the triggers for this script, or change your setting for receiving future failure notifications, click here.
>
> The script is used by the document SED - PRD.
>
> Summary:
>
> Error Message  Count
>
> Must be ###-###-####.  7

---

> Start  Function    Error Message   Trigger End
>
> 5/14/19 5:55 AM    myOnEdit    Must be ###-###-####.   edit    5/14/19 5:55 AM

Other people are using this spreadsheet (I barely use it at all -- I'm just the tech guy) and I am unable to reproduce this error. About 70 people use it and they are not tech savvy -- they probably will not tell me they are getting this error, even if I ask them to.

However, the error notification e-mail distracts from potential "real" errors. Hence, I do not just want to turn off error notifications.

These errors are also not listed in Stackdriver Error Reporting, which is confusing. The only reason I know they are happening is because of the e-mail notification.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleScripts (.gs) are not the same as standard js.
In this case you don't need `e.message`. It should be:

```
if((e).indexOf("Must be") != -1){
```

The following test should pass if you use `(e).indexOf`, but it should fail with `(e.message).indexOf`:

1. Create an empty spreadsheet and add the script below
2. Add 'onMyEdit(B1)' to cell A1
3. Add 'testfunction(B1)' to cell A2
4. Type 3 in B2

```
function onMyEdit(input){
  var inputString = ''+input;
  if(inputString.indexOf(3)!=-1) {
     throw "Must be";
    } else {
     Logger.log('success', input);
     return 0;
   }
}

function testfunction(cell) {
  try {
    onMyEdit(cell);
  } catch (e) {
    if((e).indexOf("Must be")!==-1) {
      return 'failure';
    }
  }
  return 'success';
}
```

Comment: Let me update my answer with a test you can try to verify.

Comment: Apologies, you're right! All of my tests were using actual script errors which are actually printable using `e.message`, didn't realise formulas just return `undefined` when using `e.message`. Deleted my original comment as it was misleading, thanks for the extra info.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I am a big fan of custom GoogleSheets scripts, but they can be hard to debug. If you don't mind, please upvote my answer as the correct solution. Cheers, -Ben

Comment: Interesting. I use (e.message).indexOf in tens of other places and it works as expected. Is (e.message) specific to data validation?

I will try it and upvote you if it works, but I'm curious why (e.message).indexOf works elsewhere in .gs files, but not here.

Comment: Is it possible that you are throwing your error as a string without declaring that it is an error, like I did in the test? e.message works if you use `throw Error("Must be")`

Comment: I am not throwing the error, I am catching it.

Using e.indexOf now produces the error, "TypeError: Cannot find function indexOf in object Exception: Must be ###-###-####." So this is not the answer (or I'm implementing it wrong).

Comment: I see. When you said, `all the data validation errors are custom set to an error message...`, I thought you were throwing the error explicitly in another part of the code.

Comment: I can see how it came across that way and I apologize for being unclear. Sheets let you set an error message -- Sheets calls it "validation help text" -- but the actual error is thrown by Sheets. For instance, if you set a cell's data validation criteria to "Number" and the help text to "I love dinosaurs," then use a script to grab the range (sheet.getRange()) containing the cell when it's not a number, you get the error, "I love dinosaurs." You choose the message, Sheets throws the error.